# Call logs restore in android

Tags: android

I am creating an application in android for call logs backup and restore using csv file.Backup was successfully created but while restoring all call logs  are not restored from csv.Here is the code i am writing for backup

```
 while((row = csvReader.readNext()) != null)
                     {
                    RestoreCallLogs(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]);

                    }



public  void RestoreCallLogs(String Name,String number,String Date,String Type,String Duration){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, number);
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, Date);
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION,Duration);
        values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, Type);

        if(Name!="Unknown")
         values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, Name);
        getContentResolver().insert(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a try-catch block which is hiding the exception generated here:

```
RestoreCallLogs(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]);
```

You should not use try-catch without understanding what it does.

To fix:

```
String[] row;
while((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null){
    row = line.split(",");
    RestoreCallLogs(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]);
}
```

Please read the documentation for `.split()`.  You will need to do extra work to deal with commas and other non-alphanumeric characters inside strings of a contact record.  You are also assuming that the csv only contains 5 columns. Can you guarantee that?

Finally, please use accepted conventions for naming identifiers in Java.  Using a capital letter to start a variable name makes your code hard to read.

[EDIT]

I don't know how your code compiles.  Please show the declarations for `row` and `csvReader`.

Comment: I know the schema of call logs table and i am only getting these 5 records and secondly if there will be any exception than it goes to catch block where i have worked for it